# Difference in fonts in seemingly equal enviroments

Tags: css, laravel, fonts, bootstrap-4

I have two installations of Laravel including Bootstrap.

As far as I can see both include and have `Montserrat` on the body tag.

One of the installations needs no declaration of that in the app.sass (meaning it gets included with the bootstrap directly).

However, the other needs it, otherwise it defaults to the browser default font.

And yet, even when both installations have the same Montserrat `@import`-ed, they look different. I suspect the wrong one is really Montserrat, while the right one is some kind of Bootstrap sugar-coating that the other one can't do.

In order to check it out, please follow:

**Desired effect:** [This link](http://devcast.inscription.bg/admin/calendar) and once you log in with `maximilian.berbechelov@gmail.com` and `123456` click it again. I know it's Cyrillic, but I don't think it matters.

**Problematic effect:**
[This link](http://reservations.inscription.bg/admin/schedule) - no login required.

I have a body font-family declaration in the sass file (the desired one has no such declaration), because without it the font is the browser default.

Comment: This is presently off-topic, as the issue is not recorded in the question itself; once you fix the website, the question will no longer reflect the problem you were having. Please edit the question to include a Stack Snippet or JS Fiddle.

Comment: From the official close reasons: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself._

Answer (score 1):

You can see your font adding !important after the font-family name like this.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 50px 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif!important;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #1de099, #1dc8cd);
}
.navbar-brand {
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 2.1rem;
}
```

Comment: I have deleted it for a test - now it's back, but no changes are observed.

Comment: I have changed my answer

Comment: I'm adding it and it seemingly shows the font, but there's still a notable difference. The HTML code is identical - notice the "Свободен" in the green labels below has different "в". I think the "correct" page's Bootstrap is somehow replacing the Montserrat maybe.

Comment: To have the same of the first page add also sans-serief like this.

Comment: Added, still no reaction.

Comment: Actually now has changed. Maybe you need to empty you cache to see it.
The only place where is still the old style is in the brand.
I update again my code to fix also that..

Comment: After numerous cache clears I still see the correct version like this: http://prntscr.com/mjjmvo and the wrong one like this: http://prntscr.com/mjjn8g Maybe I should just let it go.

Comment: I'm sorry Maximilian, I did my best